# How do I change a linux kernel for an EC2 friendly version?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, amazon-ec2, xen

I have to get an old image from a physical ubuntu (dapper) box into AWS. The software stack and applications are not exactly contemporary so I have tried to do a P2V to AWS

dd'd the /dev/sda volume ok Mounted it on another ubuntu AWS instance to fix up ssh keys, fstab, networking etc

but now it won't boot ( not that I am surprised ) says:

```
Tpmfront:Error Unable to read device/vtpm/0/backend-id during tpmfront initialization! error =     ENOENT Tpmfront:Info Shutting down tpmfront 
xc: error: panic: xc_dom_bzimageloader.c:655:     
xc_dom_probe_bzimage_kernel: boot protocol too old (0204): Invalid kernel xc: error: panic:  
xc_dom_core.c:621: xc_dom_find_loader: no loader found: Invalid kernel
```

How do I change the kernel (manually) to a more AWS friendly version?

Comment: Follow the using your own Kernels on AWS guide? - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/UserProvidedKernels.html

Comment: Alas no good for dapper, to old for PV-GRUB

Comment: One option is to get working in another virtual environment like VMWare / VirtualBox / etc and upgrade the kernel and test it where you have more control and have access to the various upgrade tools in the distribution itself. Then move it to EC2.